# How to get kubernetes service as spec yaml after has been `exposed`?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm very new to kubernetes and I find it a bit confusing and to understand I'd like to know what exactly  `kubectl expose deployment xxx--type=LoadBalancer --name=xxx` does. So I was wondering if is possible to extract this service to yaml spec definition somehow.

I understand that Im creating a service, but not sure how he figures out all the ports automatically. I'd like to have the same thing in a file to run it like `kubectl apply -f ./service.yaml`.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ in this you can see how to define a service..It uses properties called port and targetPort to figure out the ports

Comment: I also recommend you to read a book called k8s in action for mastering k8s

Comment: I know how to define from scratch, but I don't know the exact thing that `kubectl expose deployment xxx--type=LoadBalancer --name=xxx` does. I'd like to get that exact service out of the command somehow... In the service yaml itself I need to put each port, on this command I don't need.

Comment: Thanks, but tbh I'm a small guy, I don't have time to invest so much in kube. I already need to do the full stack. I just use kube as a simple way to deploy my docker to one instance. Nothing fancy

Comment: To generate the yaml add the following at the end of the command —dry-run=client -o yaml  You can also add   > myYaml.yaml at the end if you want to save it to a file directly.

Comment: @camba1 thats exactly what I needed! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

kubectl expose doesnot assign ports automatically. If any port defination mentioned in deploymwnt yaml then only it uses the port. otherwise it will give error like :

```
error: couldn't find port via --port flag or introspection
```

to assign port on run use:

```
kubectl expose deployment xxx --type=NodePort --name=xxx --port=80 --target-port=8080
```

you can get the yaml by running this:

```
kubectl get service xxx -o yaml
```

Comment: I meant that if I create the service.yaml with no ports he can't figure out the ports. But if I run `expose` he can figure out the ports from deployment config... Thanks for the ` -o yaml` also very useful to understand what is going on

Comment: thats called introspection. It will check the resource first which is being exposed, here its deployment.

From doc:
'''The port that the service should serve on. Copied from the resource being exposed, if unspecified'''